# Encoding data sets with Sequel (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, sequel

we are using Sequel to implement some data migration. The old legacy application uses a proprietary character set to store Umlaut-Characters (ÖÄÜ etc.)

Is there a way to hook in a conversion procedures to encode string types when Sequel processes result sets from the database?

Currently we have to perform this conversion in every place when processing result sets (which works, but pollutes the code). Performing the conversion on the database level by using functions is also an option, but makes SQL statements quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this may be the best type of fix:

```
DB.extend_datasets do
  def fetch_rows(*)
    super do |h|
      h.each_value{|v| v.replace(fix_encoding(v)) if v.is_a?(String)}
      yield h
    end
  end

  def fix_encoding(s)
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, it may be best to fix this at the driver level, in which case you should talk to the maintainer of the underlying database driver.